# I get internal server error when i try to hit api endpoint from postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I am new to aws.I have this code.
When i try with serverless offline,or when i test the api on the aws console it works great,
but when i hit the endpoint after successfully deploy in postman,i get internal server error message.
Also there are no logs in the cloud.

Please help

```
module.exports.hello = function(event, context, callback) {

  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Hello World!' }),
  };

  callback(null, response);
};
```

My yml file

```
service: serverless-test
plugins:
  - serverless-offline


provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
include:
 - utils/**
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
         path: message
         method: get
```

Comment: "there are no logs in the cloud" - do you mean no logs from your lambda in CloudWatch? If that's the case then your Lambda isn't executing, so the error is occurring before then. That being said, in my experience "internal server error" is usually an unhandled exception in the Lambda, but I couldn't say other things couldn't also result in that error.

Comment: How are you deploying it?

Comment: With sls deploy i am deploying

Comment: If you are using API-gateway to invoke the lambda function. Pls make sure the API-gateway has permission to invoke the lambda function. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-lambda-stage-variable-500/#:~:text=This%20error%20occurs%20if%20your,automatically%20adds%20the%20required%20permissions.